# Understanding weird bug with promises and undefined var

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, router

I've just discovered that my API is doing weird things when 2 requests are triggered at almost the same time.

I figured out that the issue was me missing the "var" declaration before my "user" variable below, but I'm really curious about the root issue that caused the bug described below:

I have two API endpoints that call the same function as follow:

```
router.get('/refresh_session_token', function (req, res) {

   let user_id = req.body.user_id // The value sent is 8

   findUserWithId(user_id)
    .then(user_data => {
      user = user_data // I forgot 'var' here
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(user) // This should always show user data from user_id = 8
    })
}


router.get('/resend_invite', function (req, res) {

   let user_id = req.body.user_id // The value sent is 18

   findUserWithId(user_id)
    .then(user_data => {
      user = user_data // I forgot 'var' here
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(user) // This should always show user data from user_id = 18
    })
}

const findUserWithId = (id) => {
  return knex.raw(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`, [id]).then((data) => data.rows[0])
}
```

All this code is in the same file that I export through module.exports = router;

What I discovered is that if I trigger the endpoints **/refresh_session_token** and **/resend_invite** at almost the same time each with two different user_id, it happens that sometimes, my console.log returns the same result for both as if I was using the same user_id.

Adding var to user fixed the issue but I'm very surprised as to what is actually happening on the background.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: All the requests run in the same node.js process. So they share the same global variables.

Comment: Put `"use strict";` as the first line in your module and you won't be allowed to use these accidental global variables that can kill a server with asynchronous operations in the request handlers.  Your two routes were both trying to share the same global variable because you didn't declare it.  Also, don't use `var`.  Use `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't declare your variable and you aren't running your module in Javascript's `strict` mode, then the first assignment to that variable with:

```
user = user_data
```

creates an automatic global variable named `user`.  This means that your two routes are then sharing that same variable.

And, since your two routes both have asynchronous operations in them, even with the single-threadedness of things, your two routes can still be in-flight at the same time and both trying to use the same global variable.  One route will overwrite the value from the other.  This is a disaster in server-based code because usually, the bug won't show until you get into production and it will be really, really hard to find a reproducible case.

The best answer here is to always run your code in strict mode and then the JS interpreter will make this an error and you will never be allowed to run your code this way in the first place.  The error will be found very quickly and easily.

Then obviously, always declare variables with `let` or `const`.  There are very, very few reasons to ever use `var` any more as `let` and `const` give you more control over the scope of your variable.

To run your module in strict mode, insert this:

```
'use strict';
```

before any other Javascript statements.

Or, use something like TypeScript that doesn't let you do sloppy things like not declare your variables.

Comment: Thank you ! This is indeed the right answer :).
Can I just add 'use strict' in my app.js or should it be on all files (/routes, etc)?

Comment: @johnson23 - Some code is automatically in strict mode already such as any code that's part of a `class` definition or any code in the newer ESM modules.  Outside of that, it's my opinion that you should put `'use strict';` at the start of each file.